# Use c# Null-Coalescing Operator with an int

Tags: c#, null-coalescing-operator

I'm trying to use the null-coalescing operator on an int.  It works when I use it on strings

```
UserProfile.Name = dr["Name"].ToString()??"";
```

When I try to use it on an int like this

```
UserProfile.BoardID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["BoardID"])??default(int);
```

I get this error message

> Operator '??' cannot be applied to
>   operands of type 'int' and 'int'

I found this blog post where it is used http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/07/05/NullCoalescingOperator.aspx with the int data type.  Can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suspect what you're really trying to do is set BoardID to 0 if dr["BoardID"] is NULL from the database. Because if dr["BoardID"] IS null, Convert.ToInt32 will fail. Try this:

```
UserProfile.BoardID = (dr["BoardID"] is DbNull) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(dr["BoardID"]);
```

Comment: I think the preferred check is `dr["BoardID"] == DbNull.Value`

Comment: +1 for being the only person to actually try to determine what the user was trying to do instead of go on an on about value and reference types.

Comment: @juharr: I do think it is important for OP to understand why he got the error, but several others already explained that. I just took a wag at what he was really trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 7):

An `int` is never `null`, so applying `??` to it makes no sense.

One way to achieve what you want is `TryParse`:

```
int i;
if(!int.TryParse(s, out i))
{
    i = 0;
}
```

Or since you want to get `0` or `default(int)` you can throw out the if, since the output parameter of `TryParse` in the error case is already `default(int)`:

```
int i;
int.TryParse(s, out i);
```

The article you linked doesn't have `int` on the left side of `??` but `int?`. This is a shortcut for `Nullable<int>`, which supports `null` thus `??` makes sense with it.

```
int? count = null;    
int amount = count ?? default(int); //count is `int?` here and can be null
```

Comment: There is no indication that `dr["BoardID"]` is an instance of `string`.

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, of course... because `int` can't be null.
It only has 32 bits, and all combinations represent a valid integer.

Use `int?` instead, if you want nullability. (It's shorthand for `System.Nullable<int>`.)

Answer (score 1):

In your link `??` operator is applied to `Nullable<int>` (`int?`) which can have null value.

Null-coalescing operator works in the following way:

If the value on the left of the operator is null then return the value on the right of the operator. Int is value type, so it can never have null value. That is why you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you linked the lines with the `??` operator on `int` are:

```
int? count = null;

int amount = count ?? default(int);
```

Hence in that example int is nullable

Answer (score -1):

You can only use the null-coalescing operator on reference types, or nullable value types. For example: `string`, or `int?` See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

Comment: An `int?` is not a reference type.

Comment: It is a nullable type though, which will do.

Comment: @Jon Egerton: Yes, of course, but the statement that you can only use the null-coalescing operator on reference types is false.

Comment: @Jon: Answer implies that int? is a reference type, which is wrong.